# res.json is not a function in Node.js module

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to setup google recaptcha using this tutorial (https://codeforgeek.com/2016/03/google-recaptcha-node-js-tutorial/) and move the recaptcha code into it's own module. I get:

```
TypeError: res.json is not a function
```

in the console when I try this code:

```
var checkRecaptcha = function(req, res){
    // g-recaptcha-response is the key that browser will generate upon form submit.
    // if its blank or null means user has not selected the captcha, so return the error.

    if(req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === undefined || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === '' || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === null) {
        return res.json({"responseCode" : 1,"responseDesc" : "Please select captcha"});
    }

    // Put your secret key here.
    var secretKey = "************";

    // req.connection.remoteAddress will provide IP address of connected user.
    var verificationUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretKey + "&response=" + req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] + "&remoteip=" + req.connection.remoteAddress;

    // Hitting GET request to the URL, Google will respond with success or error scenario.
    var request = require('request');
    request(verificationUrl,function(error,response,body) {

        body = JSON.parse(body);
        // Success will be true or false depending upon captcha validation.
        if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
            return res.json({"responseCode" : 1,"responseDesc" : "Failed captcha verification"});
        }
        return res.json({"responseCode" : 0,"responseDesc" : "Sucess"});
    });
}

module.exports = {checkRecaptcha};
```

Why does this happen? I do have `app.use(bodyParser.json());` set in my app.js and `res.json()` seems to work fine in other parts of my app, just not this recaptcha module.

Comment: How are you using/including the module/middleware you've shown? (Also, `bodyParser.json()` is for *parsing* JSON requests, not sending JSON responses)

Comment: is there a specific line where you get the error?

Comment: @jonathanGB I get the error on line 7, 23, and 25 (which depends on the google recaptcha response).

Comment: @mscdex I'm using passportjs when the form is submitted.
` app.post('/login',
  function(req, res, next) {
   var recaptcha = require('./recaptcha');
   recaptcha.checkRecaptcha(req, function(err, response) {
 //rest of the code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your usage of the middleware, you're not passing `res` to the function, but instead a callback (and `checkRecaptcha()` doesn't have a callback parameter since it responds directly to the request).

Try this instead:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var recaptcha = require('./recaptcha');
  recaptcha.checkRecaptcha(req, res);
});
```

or more simply:

```
app.post('/login', require('./recaptcha'));
```